# Android with Eclipse: another "the application has stopped unexpectedly, please try again"

Tags: android, eclipse

I use a virtual android device on Eclipse
When I write:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button but = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            but.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

it works, what I want to appear appears on the device, but when I just add

```
EditText taille = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taille);
```

in the function onCreate, I get a "the application has stopped unexpectedly, please try again", I often have those messages and I know where it comes from as nothing is written on the logcat, and the console has no error.

Comment: you mean the emulator crashes ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'd guess that `taille` isn't an `EditText`, thus you're getting a cast error. Run in debug and post your logcat.

Comment: yes, I have to "force close" the application

Comment: add your xml layout code also then it will be easy to answer

Comment: 323go was right, really sorry I did mix up between the android:id and android:hint of my EditText, I got the wrong ID that's why it didn't work. Sorry and thanks again!
Yet: how can I see this error with the debug tool?